# Vertical scrollpane problem in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog

I am doing a project in Java Swing.  I have a `JDialog` which contains lot of text.  I want the `JDialog` to be small and have a vertical scrollbar so that user can scroll to see the information in the `JDialog`.  How can I get a vertical scrollbar for my `JDialog`?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have long text use JtextArea with word wrap in it. Add that text area to JScrollPane and add scrollpane to your jdialog and its done. Now you will scroll when your text grows.

Example:-

```
    JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
    jTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jTextArea.setLineWrap(true);

    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Comment: hi hary how can i make the jlabel set its width according to the jscrollpane size?

Comment: Actually i have a file with data.I need to display that data in jdialog.I took a scrollpane and in that i placed a label and pasted the data with html tags. but the data is not adjusting to the size of the scrollpane

Comment: @hemanth: Instead of JLabel use JTextArea as I have already suggested in my answer.

Comment: yes i have used jtext area and i can scroll through the data now.But one more problem is when the dialog is displayed the scroll is at the end of the data. i have to scroll it up to see.